# dart: generic: the value of the local variable ' ' isn't used

Tags: dart

Can you see what is wrong with the following generics?

You can see and modify this code here: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/c417f62f2134a7ab828b36ba70564a8d

```
// import 'dart:async';

typedef void PrintFunction<T>(String p1, T p2);

class ClassA<String, T> {
  String str;
  T myprinter;

  ClassA({this.str, this.myprinter});
}

class ClassB {
  String str;
}

main() {

var smallClass = ClassB();
var hello = "input string";

PrintFunction<ClassB> mp = (hello, smallClass)=> print('Hello from PrintFunction');

  ClassA s = ClassA(
      str: "",
      myprinter: mp
  );
  s.myprinter();

}
```

Analyser error, is strange:

```
The value of the local variable 'smallClass' isn't used.
The value of the local variable 'hello' isn't used.
```

Comment: Properly formatted code is way easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work

```
    var s = MyClasse<String>(
    t1: "",
    myprinter: p);
```

You should also be aware that in

```
class MyClasse<T1, MyPrinter>
```

`MyPrinter` introduces a generic type variable and that this doesn't refer to `typedef void MyPrinter`

Comment: Thanks Günter, I am not sure I understand - I have created a gist, if you like to give it a go :-) I changed some naming, but the problem and structure is the same.

Comment: `class ClassA<String, PrintFunction> {` looks bad. As already mentioned you are mixing up types and generic type variables. For example ’String` and `PrintFunction` in `class ClassA<String, PrintFunction> {` are a very bad idea. Use `T` and `V` instead (or similar names)

Comment: Totally agree, changed to <T>. But still same problem, though it might have moved to "The value of the local variable 'smallClass' isn't used." And same for the other parameter "hello".

Comment: Why fo you think `smallClass` is used?

Comment: Using it in the constructor for ClassA in the function of PrintFunction?

Comment: No you don't. That's just the name of a parameter of the function you assign to `mp` and completely unrelated.